# Too much difference in total run time of an update query with and without quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query similar to the one below

```
Update Table1 
 Set colum1 = 'XYZ'
 Where column2 in (1,2,3,....so on)
```

Here **Column2** is of datatype varchar. In my actual query the **IN** clause contains no.of values ranging from 10000 to 60000 i.e, the query would be updating 10000 to 60000 rows.

Now when I supply the values without quotes it took 10 minutes for the query to execute. Same query when i gave the quotes(like mentioned below) it took less than a minute.

```
Update Table1*
 Set colum1 = 'XYZ'
 Where column2 in ('1','2','3',....so on)
```

Is this natural? Only difference between the above two queries is that the former needs to implicitly cast the values in **IN** clause. Can some one please explain? Thanks

Comment: Have you compared execution plans?

Comment: Compare execution plans for both queries - you will see that SQL can not use index scan (for IN clause) when it needs to convert values.

Comment: Yes I did. I noticed that SQL uses **index scan** when it converts and **index seek** when no conversion is needed. Then I found out that index seek is the faster. Implicit conversion is the culprit I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is common where a character string has been used to store a numeric key.  SQL Server will dutifully perform the implicit conversion and return the correct result, but at the cost of poor performance by doing a scan instead of a seek and using the index correctly.  -> [SOURCE](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1734/convert-implicit-and-the-related-performance-issues-with-sql-server/)